# Allow php to run shell script with sudo permission

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, script, php, sudoers

command php -v is working when I execute simple shell_exec('./script.sh'); but when I use sudo it doesn't work without sudo service stop command is not working.

**`var_dump(shell_exec('sudo bash ./script.sh'));`** this command return

**sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified**

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
php -v 

sudo service  apache2 stop
```

**command.php**

```
<?php

echo shell_exec('./script.sh');
echo shell_exec('sudo bash ./script.sh');  # not working
?>
```

**ls -la**

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data root    68 Jun 15 02:24 script.sh
```

**/etc/sudoers **

```
sudo visudo

apache  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash /var/www/html/script.sh *
www-data  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash /var/www/html/script.sh *
```

**OS**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Answer (score 1):

From command prompt, run

```
sudo visudo
```

Then go to the last line of the file and add the following line:

```
%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: <Your-Command-Here>
```

Hope this helps!